# Why does this sentence involving "especial" read so badly?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have read about the difference between "special" and "especial" and from what I understand they are basically the same. However I've come across a sentence which, in my opinion, would sound much better with "special". Is the following sentence correct and if yes why does it sound so poor?

> No especial skill is required to use the tool

Comment: "In American English the adjective `special` is overwhelmingly more common than `especial` in all senses." - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/special

Comment: However I would not mind _You need a lot of skills, especially with this tool_

Comment: Especially since 'especially' is not an adjective.

Comment: Rather than concentrate upon the subtle difference between special and especial I would suggest that the incorrect spelling of "read" is much more likely to attract the reader's attention.

Comment: and the use of *bad* as an adverb.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Andrew Leach's answer about *why* the sentence sounds bad, but I think "special" does not capture the essence of what is being said.

If you look at the first set of definitions for "especial" [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/especial), you can see two definitions - the first corresponding to "special", the second being:

> "of a particular kind, or peculiar to a particular one; particular: your especial case."

I think that from the context, it is the *second* meaning that is intended; an alternative phrasing that captures the intended meaning might therefore be:

> No *particular* skill is required to use the tool

Answer (score 2):

It reads badly because of the two vowel sounds together ("No es-"); in the OED's citations for *especial*, all but one (from 1640) precede the word with a consonant sound.

However, there is a more subtle reason.

*Especial* is archaic. Archaisms have a function in English, but that function is to draw attention to themselves.

With *especial*, one might write either of

- A special skill is required
- An especial skill is required

but using *especial* calls attention to it. It must be a **really** special skill.

When you're saying that **no** special skill is required, why use a word like *especial*, with its "**really** special" sense? It's pointless drawing attention to the speciality of the skill when it's not required.